# How can tsfile detected its possible damage when transferring between different servers of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Does tsfile itself have a verification mechanism in Apache IoTDB? I wonder if the tsfile storage is damaged during transfer progress between different IoTDB servers, will this damage be detected when executing `load` to IoTDB database? Do I need to manually try to load again if this error happened?

Answer (score 0):

If tsfile is damaged during the transfer process of Apache IoTDB servers, it can be detected when loading into the received server, and also it will be automatically retried to be transmitted, so you don't need to manually setup any transmission settings.